# Facebook Leadgen app turned off itself

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

Does facebook turn off Leadgen webhook app of its own. I have one app running without any problem, but today when I was not getting webhooks I checked and found that the app was turned off.

Does the leadgen webhook app requires to submit for approval?

I tried finding an answer on FB but no luck.

Comment: Facebook disables webhooks if your callback URL did not respond correctly for a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your weebhook App didn't require an approval to works for in a leadgen integration. In development mode you webhook app only be used by administrators, developers and testers. You can keep like this.

Check your app token or page token if it has expired, using this link:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken

Check your webhoook app is subscribed into your page, and submit a lead test the track status with this links: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lead-ads-testing

Check a role permission in your Facebook Page, from what I remember you must be a administrator.

If none of these checks help, there may be something wrong with weebhook.

Comment: Thanks!! I think the problem was caused by my PHP script , I do have error in a module. I corrected that and its working fine.